# Creating a Random Number Generator in Java - Array resetting each time

Tags: java

I am trying to create my own Random Number Generator in Java and have been using the Lagged Fibonacci formula.

It works when I want to grab one random number, but when I want to generate multiple random numbers it is just pulling the same random number for all iterations rather than holding on to the new array to generate the next random number.

```
public class RNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RandomNumberGenerator rd = new RandomNumberGenerator();
        int number = rd.getNumber();

        System.out.println(number);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            int number2 = rd.getNumber();
            System.out.println(number2);
        }

    }

}
```

```
public class RandomNumberGenerator {

    public static int getNumber() {
        long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();     // start seed number for formula
        int length = (int) (Math.log10(seed) + 1);  // number of digits int the seed number
        int j = 3;                                  // will always grab the 3rd value from the seed
        int k = 7;                                  // will always grab the 7th value from the seed
        int mod = 10;                               // will always be the mod number for formula 
        int[] arr = new int[length + 1];            // array for seed numbers
        String stseed = String.valueOf(seed);       // seed to String for adding digits to array    

        // Take the seed number and turn it into an array of single digit numbers to mimic a sequence
        for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
            arr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(stseed.charAt(i));
        }   

        // calculate random number with inputs
        int number = (arr[length - j] + arr[length - k]) % mod;

        // add random number to the end of the array in the temp index
        arr[length] = number;

        // update array by shifting all indexes down
        for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }

        return number;
    }

}
```

Comment: to some mathematics with current time. You will get random number every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `getNumber()` you re-initialize the state of the generator. If you call this multiple times within the same millisecond, you'll initialize it to the same state every time, so you'll end up with the same value. (Even if you call it multiple times over a longer time period, only some of the digits will change, so you still may end up with the same result.)

You need to cache the state, and initialize it once:

```
public class RandomNumberGenerator {

    private static long seed ;     // start seed number for formula
    private static int length ;  // number of digits int the seed number
    private static final int j = 3;                                  // will always grab the 3rd value from the seed
    private static final int k = 7;                                  // will always grab the 7th value from the seed
    private static final int mod = 10;                               // will always be the mod number for formula 
    private static int[] arr ;            // array for seed numbers

    static {
        seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        length = (int) (Math.log10(seed) + 1) ;
        arr = new int[length + 1] ;
        String stseed = String.valueOf(seed);       // seed to String for adding digits to array    

        // Take the seed number and turn it into an array of single digit numbers to mimic a sequence
        for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
            arr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(stseed.charAt(i));
        }   

    }

    public static int getNumber() {

        // calculate random number with inputs
        int number = (arr[length - j] + arr[length - k]) % mod;

        // add random number to the end of the array in the temp index
        arr[length] = number;

        // update array by shifting all indexes down
        for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }

        return number;
    }

}
```

I'd recommend not making everything static (especially since you don't use it in a static fashion in your `main` method):

```
public class RandomNumberGenerator {

    private long seed ;     // start seed number for formula
    private int length ;  // number of digits int the seed number
    private static final int j = 3;                                  // will always grab the 3rd value from the seed
    private static final int k = 7;                                  // will always grab the 7th value from the seed
    private static final int mod = 10;                               // will always be the mod number for formula 
    private int[] arr ;            // array for seed numbers

    public RandomNumberGenerator() {
        seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        length = (int) (Math.log10(seed) + 1) ;
        arr = new int[length + 1] ;
        String stseed = String.valueOf(seed);       // seed to String for adding digits to array    

        // Take the seed number and turn it into an array of single digit numbers to mimic a sequence
        for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
            arr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(stseed.charAt(i));
        }   

    }

    public int getNumber() {

        // calculate random number with inputs
        int number = (arr[length - j] + arr[length - k]) % mod;

        // add random number to the end of the array in the temp index
        arr[length] = number;

        // update array by shifting all indexes down
        for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }

        return number;
    }


}
```